# How to read numbers from JSON with different class in the same field?

Tags: java, arrays, json

I am trying to extract "sentiment"value from JSON file.

```
{
  "id": 1140,
  "company": "Barclays",
  "title": "Barclays set to name former JPMorgan banker Staley as new CEO",
  "sentiment": 0.000
},
{
  "id": 1141,
  "company": "Kingfisher",
  "title": "Kingfisher share price slides on cost to implement new strategy",
  "sentiment": -0.786
},
```

If I am not mistaken, "-0.786" is double while "0.000" is a long.The first few output is success until :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
```

I am very new in this, is there any method to solve this or anything to refer to?

Code:

```
public static void printScore(String data)
{
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    String link = data;

    try {     
        JSONArray a = (JSONArray) parser.parse(new FileReader(link));

        for (Object o:a){
            JSONObject jsonObject =  (JSONObject) o;

            double score = (double) jsonObject.get("sentiment");
            //DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(#.###);
            System.out.format("%.3f",score);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: They are both floating point.

Comment: is there anything i can do? The first few read is fine, but it will stop running  when hitting 0.000

Comment: Why will it stop? You can't use a `long`. It is not a long. Use a `double`

Comment: This is the problem. I am using doubles, and the first 30ish reading is fine, and then it stopped and give me the error shown above.

Comment: You should clean up your code. So many casts, crazy exception handling.

Comment: Before this, I was using the code to read a JSON file with similar case, but all the value is Int, which works well. In this case, if cleaning up the exception will help my situation, I will do it.

Comment: JSON does not define `int`. It just has `number` which maps most closely to `double`. You should fix your code because you should fix your code.

Comment: If the code you recommend me to clean up will affect the outcome? Why not focus to make the code get the outcome I need and the clean up later?

Comment: Why are you asking?

Comment: I asked a question, regarding how to read a data that the system told me have different class( I read 'double' and it worked for 20ish instances, and then the system told me it cannot read 'long'). And in the middle of discussion, you ask me to clean up my "crazy exception handling". So, I am asking, is the part you ask me to clean up affect my outcome?

Comment: Sorry, I don't particularly care at this point. You should not need me to motivate you to improve your code.

Comment: Why should I decorate my car before it could run? Usually, I will not answer other people's question if I am not experienced or prepared. Even if I helped, and I found out it is beyond my reach, I'd say " sorry mate, can't help you". Oh, thanks for the help

Comment: I'm not sure what you are getting at. Your code is failing with exceptions due to invalid casts. I pointed out that you have casts all over the place and without a good reason. I also mentioned your exception handling. If you do not care, why not just catch the cast exception? It is a terrible idea, but so is catching a parsing exception in this context.

Comment: Yes, dear, you pointed out, and I asked is the cleaning up the code can affect my outcome, and then you helpfully replied me "You should fix your code because you should fix your code.", instead of "yes", or "you should do this".

Comment: You realize your code would just work if you stopped casting right? Seriously just print it and be done.

Comment: In my question, I wrote:"I am very new in this, is there any method to solve this or anything to refer to?" I not polite and I am being literal. and no, I did not realize, that's why i asked for a solution/suggestion.

Comment: I don't think you did well to write that and have no idea why you would repeat it.

Comment: Yeah. and I thought someone who guide me in my internship but instead I need to do this stuff using a language that I never learn to complete the task in a certain time frame.

Comment: That's a self-defeating attitude, there is no way around learning this stuff and the only way you can learn it by using it. Yes it is hard but it gets easier with practice. Consider also that the issues I've suggested that you address relate to your writing too much code. I'm telling you to write less, not more.

Comment: Yes, I am in the progress in learning Java, but not until this level yet. To be honest, I copied this code from stackoverflow, and it worked on every file, except this one...Anyhow, thanks for the tips...I have to go back now before I trapped myself in 2 hour traffic jam. bye

Comment: I figured you did not understand it. That is why I encouraged you to take it apart. Since you did not write it. I have no interest in assisting you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
package com.test;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;

import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonIOException;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException;

public class Json {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printScore("test.json");
    }

    public static void printScore(String data) {
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        String link = data;
        JsonArray a;
        try {
            a = (JsonArray) parser.parse(new FileReader(link));
            for (Object o : a) {
                JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) o;
                double score = jsonObject.get("sentiment").getAsDouble();
                System.out.format("%.3f", score);
            }
        } catch (JsonIOException | JsonSyntaxException | FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks For the help. It worked and I learn something new. Thanks